# How to make 'var data = data2[i]' to an object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve by creating an object from a variable inside a for loop.

For Example:

```
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 5];
var output = {}; 
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) { 
 var message = "Array number : " + arr[i]; //var
 output = {number : message}; //obj
 console.log('Output', output);
}
```

But, I'm not sure the logic is correct.

the output I'm expetcing to be

```
Output: {
          number:[
                 0: {"Array number: 1"},
                 1: {"Array number: 3"},
                 2: {"Array number: 4"},
                 3: {"Array number: 5"}
                ]
        }
```

or

```
Output: {
          number:{
                 "Array number: 1",
                 "Array number: 3",
                 "Array number: 4",
                 "Array number: 5"
                }
        }
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: your question formulation need to be improved... are you trying to convert array to object with key for each array item?

Comment: You can't create an object without properties name. Maybe do you want an array?

Comment: Yes, I need an array

Comment: `{"Array number: 1"}` is incorrect. It should be an array (not an object) i.e. `["Array number: 1"]`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `output` object you can take array and push it to it like

```
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 5];
var output = []; 
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) { 
   var message = "Array number : " + arr[i]; //var
   output.push( {number : message}); //obj
  }
  console.log(output)
```

Comment: or use "map" method: ;
[1, 3, 4, 5].map(num => ({num: "Array number :${num}"}))

Comment: Yes.. map method is also be possible to generate the expected out put like `[1, 3, 4, 5].map(function(num){ return "Array Number "+ num })`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 5];
var number = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) { 
 var message = "Array number : " + arr[i];
 number.push(message);
}

var output = {number};
console.log('Output', output);
```

Comment: Thanks guys was you were great help. Sorry couldn't upvote your answers because I'm new user, thanks again for the help and tips

Comment: @Pradeep You cannot upvote but you certainly can accept what you consider the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an object without properties name. If you want an array then you should do this:

```
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 5];
var output = {number: arr.map((item, index) => {
   return {index: `Array number ${item}`};
}, arr)};
console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
{
    number: [
        {0: "Array number: 1"},
        {1: "Array number: 3"},
        {2: "Array number: 4"},
        {3: "Array number: 5"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: yes, but the output is little different, how would i handle the data?

Comment: You can't have output like in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 5];
var output = {}; 
var numbers = []
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) { 
    numbers.push({'ArrayNumber' : arr[i]}); //var
}
output = {number : numbers}; //obj
console.log('Output', output);
```

Answer (score 0):

"=" is **assignment**. it's not push value into array. if your variable is json array you can push value to array like this:

```
var a = [];
a.push('value');
```

or your variable is json object:

```
var a = {};
a.key = 'value';
```